# Confusion Matrix - Get Items FP/FN/TP/TN - Python

Tags: python, confusion-matrix

After run my python code:

```
print(confusion_matrix(x_test, x_pred))
```

I get this:
[100 32
211  21]

My question is how can I get the following list:

- True positive = 100
- False positive = 32
- False negative = 211
- True negative = 21

Is this possible?

Comment: Just use list indexing? If it's in an image form, then we have to manually code them up

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Considering you have two lists y_actual and y_pred ( I assume you made a typo error on x_test and x_pred as in your code), you can pass the two lists to this function to parse them

```
def perf_measure(y_actual, y_pred):
    TP = 0
    FP = 0
    TN = 0
    FN = 0

    for i in range(len(y_pred)): 
        if y_actual[i]==y_pred[i]==1:
           TP += 1
        if y_pred[i]==1 and y_actual[i]!=y_pred[i]:
           FP += 1
        if y_actual[i]==y_pred[i]==0:
           TN += 1
        if y_pred[i]==0 and y_actual[i]!=y_pred[i]:
           FN += 1

return(TP, FP, TN, FN)
```

Alternatively, if confusion matrix is a 2x2 matrix (named cm), you can use

```
TP = cm[0][0]
FP = cm[0][1]
FN = cm[1][0]
TN = cm[1][1]
```

Answer (score 4):

Create a method that does the printing for you:

```
def print_confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred):
    cm = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
    print('True positive = ', cm[0][0])
    print('False positive = ', cm[0][1])
    print('False negative = ', cm[1][0])
    print('True negative = ', cm[1][1])
```

And use it like this

```
print_confusion_matrix(x_test, x_pred)
```

Alternatively, if you want the values return and not only printed you can do it like this:

```
def get_confusion_matrix_values(y_true, y_pred):
    cm = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
    return(cm[0][0], cm[0][1], cm[1][0], cm[1][1])

TP, FP, FN, TN = get_confusion_matrix_values(x_test, x_pred)
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case you can use

```
conf = confusion_matrix(x_test, x_pred)
TP = conf[0,0]
FP = conf[0,1]
TN = conf[1,0]
FN = conf[1,1]
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest [PyCM](https://github.com/sepandhaghighi/pycm) lib for confusion matrix analysis.

Example :

```
>>> from pycm import *
>>> y_actu = [2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2] # or y_actu = numpy.array([2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2])
>>> y_pred = [0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2] # or y_pred = numpy.array([0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2])
>>> cm = ConfusionMatrix(actual_vector=y_actu, predict_vector=y_pred) # Create CM From Data
>>> cm.classes
[0, 1, 2]
>>> cm.table
{0: {0: 3, 1: 0, 2: 0}, 1: {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2}, 2: {0: 2, 1: 1, 2: 3}}
>>> print(cm)
Predict          0        1        2        
Actual
0                3        0        0        
1                0        1        2        
2                2        1        3        




Overall Statistics : 

95% CI                                                           (0.30439,0.86228)
Bennett_S                                                        0.375
Chi-Squared                                                      6.6
Chi-Squared DF                                                   4
Conditional Entropy                                              0.95915
Cramer_V                                                         0.5244
Cross Entropy                                                    1.59352
Gwet_AC1                                                         0.38931
Joint Entropy                                                    2.45915
KL Divergence                                                    0.09352
Kappa                                                            0.35484
Kappa 95% CI                                                     (-0.07708,0.78675)
Kappa No Prevalence                                              0.16667
Kappa Standard Error                                             0.22036
Kappa Unbiased                                                   0.34426
Lambda A                                                         0.16667
Lambda B                                                         0.42857
Mutual Information                                               0.52421
Overall_ACC                                                      0.58333
Overall_RACC                                                     0.35417
Overall_RACCU                                                    0.36458
PPV_Macro                                                        0.56667
PPV_Micro                                                        0.58333
Phi-Squared                                                      0.55
Reference Entropy                                                1.5
Response Entropy                                                 1.48336
Scott_PI                                                         0.34426
Standard Error                                                   0.14232
Strength_Of_Agreement(Altman)                                    Fair
Strength_Of_Agreement(Cicchetti)                                 Poor
Strength_Of_Agreement(Fleiss)                                    Poor
Strength_Of_Agreement(Landis and Koch)                           Fair
TPR_Macro                                                        0.61111
TPR_Micro                                                        0.58333

Class Statistics :

Classes                                                          0                       1                       2                       
ACC(Accuracy)                                                    0.83333                 0.75                    0.58333                 
BM(Informedness or bookmaker informedness)                       0.77778                 0.22222                 0.16667                 
DOR(Diagnostic odds ratio)                                       None                    4.0                     2.0                     
ERR(Error rate)                                                  0.16667                 0.25                    0.41667                 
F0.5(F0.5 score)                                                 0.65217                 0.45455                 0.57692                 
F1(F1 score - harmonic mean of precision and sensitivity)        0.75                    0.4                     0.54545                 
F2(F2 score)                                                     0.88235                 0.35714                 0.51724                 
FDR(False discovery rate)                                        0.4                     0.5                     0.4                     
FN(False negative/miss/type 2 error)                             0                       2                       3                       
FNR(Miss rate or false negative rate)                            0.0                     0.66667                 0.5                     
FOR(False omission rate)                                         0.0                     0.2                     0.42857                 
FP(False positive/type 1 error/false alarm)                      2                       1                       2                       
FPR(Fall-out or false positive rate)                             0.22222                 0.11111                 0.33333                 
G(G-measure geometric mean of precision and sensitivity)         0.7746                  0.40825                 0.54772                 
LR+(Positive likelihood ratio)                                   4.5                     3.0                     1.5                     
LR-(Negative likelihood ratio)                                   0.0                     0.75                    0.75                    
MCC(Matthews correlation coefficient)                            0.68313                 0.2582                  0.16903                 
MK(Markedness)                                                   0.6                     0.3                     0.17143                 
N(Condition negative)                                            9                       9                       6                       
NPV(Negative predictive value)                                   1.0                     0.8                     0.57143                 
P(Condition positive)                                            3                       3                       6                       
POP(Population)                                                  12                      12                      12                      
PPV(Precision or positive predictive value)                      0.6                     0.5                     0.6                     
PRE(Prevalence)                                                  0.25                    0.25                    0.5                     
RACC(Random accuracy)                                            0.10417                 0.04167                 0.20833                 
RACCU(Random accuracy unbiased)                                  0.11111                 0.0434                  0.21007                 
TN(True negative/correct rejection)                              7                       8                       4                       
TNR(Specificity or true negative rate)                           0.77778                 0.88889                 0.66667                 
TON(Test outcome negative)                                       7                       10                      7                       
TOP(Test outcome positive)                                       5                       2                       5                       
TP(True positive/hit)                                            3                       1                       3                       
TPR(Sensitivity, recall, hit rate, or true positive rate)        1.0                     0.33333                 0.5  

>>> cm.matrix()
Predict          0        1        2        
Actual
0                3        0        0        
1                0        1        2        
2                2        1        3        

>>> cm.normalized_matrix()
Predict          0              1              2              
Actual
0                1.0            0.0            0.0            
1                0.0            0.33333        0.66667        
2                0.33333        0.16667        0.5
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using scikit-learn you can use it like this:

In the binary case, we can extract true positives, etc as follows:

```
tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred).ravel()
```

where `y_true` is the actual values and `y_pred` is the predicted values

See more details in the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html)

Answer (score 0):

tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(x_test,x_predictions,labels).ravel()

Answer (score 0):

```py
import sklearn    
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
actual = [1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1]
predicted = [1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1]
confusion_matrix(actual, predicted)
```

output would be

```py
array([[1, 1],
       [1, 3]])
```

For TP (truly predicted as positive), TN, FP, FN

```py
c = confusion_matrix(actual, predicted)
TN, FP, FN, TP =  confusion_matrix = c[0][0], c[0][1], c[1][0],c[1][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

@Srihari's answer works well but pays attention to the indention of the 'return'. Currently, it is written as follows:

> 

```
def perf_measure(..., ...):
   for i in range(...):
     if():
     ...

return (FP, TN, ...)
```

This return: "SyntaxError: 'return' outside function ". The normal indement should be:

> 

```
def perf_measure(..., ...):
   for i in range(...):
     if():
     ...

   return (FP, TN, ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Classification Task: Anamoly detection; (y=1 -> anamoly, y=0 -> not an anamoly)

is the number of true positives: the ground truth label says it’s an anomaly and our algorithm correctly classified it as an anomaly.
 is the number of true negatives: the ground truth label says it’s not an anomaly and our algorithm correctly classified it as not an anomaly.

 is the number of false positives: the ground truth label says it’s not an anomaly, but our algorithm incorrectly classified it as an anomaly.

 is the number of false negatives: the ground truth label says it’s an anomaly, but our algorithm incorrectly classified it as not being.

Here is a vectorized implementation.

```
def perf_measure(y_actual, y_pred):
    tp = np.sum((y_actual==1) & (y_pred==1))
    tn = np.sum((y_actual==0) & (y_pred==0))
    fp = np.sum((y_actual==0) & (y_pred==1))
    fn = np.sum((y_actual==1) & (y_pred==0))
    
    return(tp, tn, fp, fn)
```